# HttpOnly cookie can be accessed in a node client?

Tags: node.js, cookies, cookie-httponly

I'm new to node and going through some tutorials. I've got a simple node server running this code:

```
// SERVER CODE
const http = require('http');
const Cookies = require('cookies');
const port = 3000;

const requestHandler = (request, response) => {
  cookies = new Cookies(request, response);
  cookies.set("foo", "bar", { httpOnly: true });

  response.end('Hello Node.js Server!');
}

const server = http.createServer(requestHandler);

server.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', err);
  }

  console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`);
})
```

And I have another .js file that tries to access this server:

```
//CLIENT CODE
const http = require('http')

http.get('http://machine_name:3000', (
    console.log(res.headers['set-cookie']);
});
```

From my understanding, httponly cookies should be unable to be available by client Javascript. When I run the client code though, I get:

```
[ 'foo=bar; path=/; httponly' ]
```

Is this right? Am I not setting it up correctly? I feel like this is an error since the httponly property means I shouldn't be able to access it via Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is doing it in the right way and this you can try with your browser.

Si tienes un archivo index con el siguiente contenido:

```
// index.js file
const http = require('http');
const Cookies = require('cookies');
const port = 3000;

const requestHandler = (request, response) => {
  cookies = new Cookies(request, response);
  cookies.set("foo", "bar", { httpOnly: true });

  response.end('Hello Node.js Server!');
}

const server = http.createServer(requestHandler);

server.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', err);
  }

  console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`);
})
```

When you execute the command

```
node index.js
```

And you open your browser, open the console and execute the following

```
console.log( document.cookie ) // this not return your cookies
```

But if you have **{ httpOnly: false }** you can get the following:

"other-cookies; **foo=bar**"

> This is because JavaScript uses cookies more in the browser itself than in the console, if you have the httpOnly flag activated you can be 100% sure that no JS script can use it.
>
> > [Read more about cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)